# Search for all files containing only a string of a certain length

Tags: grep

I have lots of files I'm searching through to try and find the ones that contain a string of 8 characters - nothing else.

So far I've tried: -

```
grep -x '.\{8,8\}'
```

Which is showing me files that contain a string of exactly 8 characters, but also show files that contain lots of other stuff as well as the 8 characters. I want the files that contain a string of exactly 8 characters and nothing more.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: All strings that are 9 (or more) bytes long contain strings of exactly 8 characters. Did you mean lines that are exactly 8 characters long (plus the newline), or files that contain lines like that, or files/lines that contain white-space separated "words" of exactly 8 characters, or something completely different?

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for files that are 9 bytes long, eight characters and a newline.  This assumes that you are looking for single-byte characters only.

```
find . -type f -size 9c -exec grep -l -E '^.{8}$' {} +
```

This finds all regular files in or below the current directory that are exactly 9 bytes long.  To verify that they only contain a single line, we run `grep` over them and try to match a line with exactly eight characters. We let `grep` output the names of the matching files with its `-l` option.

Comment: This is fantastic - you're a wizard!

Comment: That assumes all characters in all the files are single-byte.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, it does. I will add a note about this.

Comment: @twalberg No. We have to make sure there are no other newlines in the file than at the end, otherwise we'd find a file whose contents is `red\ncat\n\n` for example.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `awk` to find regular files that contain only one line, containing exactly 8 characters (not counting the newline character if any):

```
find . -type f -size +7c -size -50c -exec gawk '
  BEGINFILE               {p = 0}
  FNR == 1 && length == 8 {p = 1}
  FNR == 2                {p = 0; nextfile}
  ENDFILE                 {if (p) print FILENAME}' {} +
```

With find, we restrict to  files whose size is in between 8 and 49 bytes. 8 for a file with 8 one-byte characters and no newline, 49 for 8 6-byte characters (the maximum in UTF-8, you may want to adapt for other charsets) and a newline.

Or with `zsh`:

```
has_one_line_of_8_characters() {
  local c
  ! read -ru0 -k10 c && [[ $c =~ $'^[^\n]{8}\n?$' ]]
} < ${1-$REPLY}

printf '%s\n' **/*(.DL+7L-50+has_one_line_of_8_characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk '/^.{9}$/{print FILENAME}' RS='\0' *
```

I chose 9 chars, because the 8 characters and the newline character in the end of line = 9 characters in total. If you need strictly 8 characters with the newline included, you should use the 8 number in the pattern.

**Testing**

I have four files in the test folder:

```
$ tail -n +1 -- *
==> 11_chars <==
zzzzzzzzzz

==> 5_chars <==
zzzz

==> 7_chars <==
zzzzzz

==> 9_chars <==
zzzzzzzz
```

**Output**

```
$ gawk '/^.{9}$/{print FILENAME}' RS='\0' *
9_chars
```